# RMarkdown LaTex Unicode Error with ggmap register_google google API

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, ggmap

I made a map using ggmap connecting to google map but when I was trying to knit the RMarkdown file into PDF, I ran into the problem of LaTex Unicode Error. Can anyone please help with that?

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ^^\[ (U+001B)
not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

The code I wrote in R is as following:

```
library(ggmap) google_api = "AIzaSyBagqJeHTLlxDajY5t01iQE2CcI7LXwOzk"       
ggmap::register_google(key=google_api) 
bbox = c(left=-125,bottom=24,right=-67,top=49) 
statesmap = ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox,zoom=5,maptype="toner-lite")) 
statesmap + geom_point(data = d3, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = cases), color="plum4",alpha = 0.3)
```

I tried to change output to:

```
output:
bookdown::pdf_document2:
latex_engine: lualatex
tufte::tufte_handout:
latex_engine: xelatex
```

But it ran into another error:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.585 ## i Google's Terms of Service:
\]8;;https://mapsplatform.google.com\<ht...
```